# X-Axis label in mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Earlier, we could set label for X-Axis using the constructor of LineData.

```
            LineData lineData = new LineData(labels,dataSet);
```

But after 3.0, it's not working. Has this been removed or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use value formatters .
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisFormatter)

Answer (score 0):

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
// here you can return whatever you want,
// for example you can return values from array, and use value argument as index
                return labels[value]);
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the `labels` variable here? How was it created?